# Путь к файлу в развернутом на WildFly приложении.

Tags: java, java-ee, jboss, wildfly

Доброго времени суток. 
В ресурсах проекта имеется файл `config.properties`. При сборке проекта IDE закидывает файл в директорию `WEB-INF/classes/` WAR файла.
А теперь непосредственно вопрос: как определить путь к папке, в которую развернётся приложение? И где будет лежать нужный файл?

Проблема в том, что при развертывании приложения (по крайней мере через среду программирования) все файлы перемещаются в генерируемую папку с, кажется, случайным названием. Поэтому даже с помощью относительного пути от домашней директории сервера (`System.getPropertie("jboss.home.dir")` ) найти файл невозможно.

Есть ли какой-то метод однозначного определения расположения развёрнутых файлов?

Comment: Может быть есть, Только properties как-то загружать без этого пути. Вообще предполагается, что в этих приложениях загрузка всяких ресурсов будет проводится без какого-либо знания о физических путях.1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160691/how-to-read-properties-file-in-web-application 2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161054/where-to-place-and-how-to-read-configuration-resource-files-in-servlet-based-app

Comment: Вот такой метод поиска относительного пути в системе я и искал. Не смог правильно сформулировать мысль (поэтому и не нагуглил). Огромное спасибо, помогло! Напишите ответ, я его отмечу: может кому-нибудь поможет.

Comment: Я всё это (по ссылкам) перевести не в состоянии. Тем более не разбираясь в тонкостях загрузки классов.

Comment: @Sergey Тогда сам отвечу. Всё равно спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего использовать `ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();`. Подобный `ClassLoader` гарантированно имеет доступ ко всем ресурсам. 
При его использовании относительный путь начинается с `WEB-INF/classes/` вашего развёрнутого приложения. Первый `/` здесь не указывается.